# Судьба кадров Ethernet с некорректной контрольной суммой

Tags: сеть

На сетевую карту приходит испорченный пакет (некорректная CRC32).

Что происходит с ним дальше? Он отбрасывается на месте или фильтруется уже на уровне драйверов или ОС? И есть ли способ его посмотреть на компьютере?

Comment: Просто есть устройство, которое при подключении к коммутатору (какое-то проф. оборудование, не металлолом) даже коротеньким, меньше метра, патч-кордом получает убитые пакеты. Я сделал показометр на базе оного девайса, он показал до 1-2% битья при приёме. С большинством иных коммутаторов даже того же производителя, даже на длинных линиях проблем, в общем-то нет. Определить бы как-нибудь достоверно (не этим показометром), что это именно коммутатор лагучий, а не есть конфликт устройства с ним. Или наоборот, что только это устройство может иногда не разбирать его передачи.

Comment: А у вас на устройстве и коммутаторе настройки скорости и дуплекса соответствуют? VLAN должен быть untagged, может, если есть вообще.

Comment: Не знаю, в те коммутаторы я залезть не могу (но вряд ли кто-то их перенастраивал от дефолтных настроек портов). Но вообще, разве они не должны сами определять, что девайс хочет 10 мбит полудуплекс?=)д-линк des-1210 вполне себе определил автоматом.

Comment: > Autonegotiation between devices that implemented it differently failed. Problems like this with autonegotiation led many network administrators to manually set the speed and duplex mode of each network interface card, and even Cisco recommended its customers not to use autonegotiation. However, the use of manually set configuration may also lead to duplex mismatchesНасколько я себе это представляю, если одна сторона под определение скорости не настроена, то на второй все тоже не здраво.

Comment: Понятно. Да уж, я попробовал. Девайс настроился в фуллдуплекс (100 Мбит он умеет, но может не успеть обработать, скорость занижена специально), коммутатор только в полудуплекс. Возможно, так правильнее было бы сделать. Проверим :зЛюбопытная ссылка по теме: http://www.brocade.com/downloads/documents/html_product_manuals/NI_05300a_DIAG/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#context=53-1002426-02_Diagnostic_Guide_NI05300a&file=L1_diagnostics.05.3.html

Comment: Хм, изменил сетевое подключение на автоопределение, но только 10 мбпс. Теперь он подключается full-duplex 10Mbps. Посмотрим, изменит ли это что-нибудь.

Comment: А напрямую девайс подключать не пробовали? Просто, для чистоты эксперимента.

Answer (score 1):

При декапсуляции и сверки CRC дропнит данный фрейм на этапе Media Access Control, поскольку нет возможности определить illegal frame на физическом уровне, без его декапсуляции. Эти уже занимается ядро ОС. Посмотреть, мне кажется, что можно, поскольку например тот же tcpdump использует библиотеку libpcap, которая в свою очередь работает до того как ядро декапсулирует. Я точно уверен, что до декапсуляции ip точно, а вот насчет ethernet не уверен.

Comment: Пятак, насколько я помню, в Ethernet, а это канальный уровень OSI, используется именно CRC-32. Так что, неправильные пакеты там просто отбрасываются.

Comment: Все верно, вы просто наверное забыли что MAC это канальный уровень.

Comment: @pyatak, сверка CRC должна в идеале происходить "On Go". Мне кажется, что как таковой деинкапсуляции там нет, поток байт с разделителями.> The FCS is often transmitted in such a way that the receiver can compute a running sum over the entire frame, including the trailing FCS, and expect to see a fixed result (such as zero) when it is correct. Such an FCS generally appears immediately before the frame-ending delimiter.`by Wendell ODOM, Ccie #1624, Cisco Official Cert Guide, Book 1, Chapter 3 : Fundamentals of LANs, Page 74`

Comment: Не все ОС возвращают FCS, тот же WireShark может попросту показывать ноль. Более того, кроме отбрасывания фрейма, необходимо оповестить передатчик.

Comment: Возьмите меня в Швейцарию. Я бы с вами подискутировал. )

Comment: А есть о чем дискутировать?

Comment: DEX, оповестить передатчик? А как определить, кто передатчик, если кадр битый?=) Хотя этот ответ интересен только из любопытства><

Comment: Здесь, я, пожалуй, перегнул, говоря о фрейме. Контроль естественно будет на более высоком уровне, например, транспортном. Конечно, Ethernet не контроллирует ничего, отбросил и с концами.

Answer (score 0):

Отбрасываются, обычно на уровне драйвера. Это канальный уровень модели OSI, и ничего более от него не требуется. Коррекция ошибок осуществляется на более высоких уровнях.

Comment: А вот драйвер это, физический уровень.

Comment: Драйвер осуществляет переход с физического на канальный.